# Composer not generating .git folder for packages

Tags: php, composer-php

This is weird, seems like something small that I'm missing. A few days ago, when I `composer install` I get Vendor directories with their own `.git`, this allows me to make changes and update my own packaged repositories.

Today, after running `composer install`, the `.git` directories inside each package folder is missing! (I think this might have something to do with installing from cache?)

Could someone please try re-create this?

```
$ git clone https://github.com/nathankot/rbhpi
$ cd rbhpi
$ ./composer.phar install
$ cd vendor/rbhpi/core
$ ls -a
```

From the above commands, the `.git` directory is missing for me.

I couldn't find this spec in the docs, but I did find it in [this faq item](http://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md):

> Remove the .git directory of every dependency after the installation

Any solutions to my problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Composer prefers the dist package of your dependencies, meaning dowloading a .tgz from github and unpacking it. If you want the source, install your vendors with

```
composer install --prefer-source
```

This will do a git checkout like you want.

Comment: and 'composer install --prefer-dist' for production (no git folders), thanks